# Ruby longest palindrome - why does a slight modification in a while loop break my code?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve this Ruby problem and I can't figure out why having a minor while loop difference renders one test false: longest_palindrome("abba") outputs "bb" instead of "abba", which is false. I can only solve it with for and while loops, so please no advanced methods. It's easier to highlight the difference in the code block (first one is the working solution, second is mine. Also assume the `palindrome?` method is already defined):

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
best_palindrome = nil

  idx1 = 0

    ***while idx1 < string.length
    length = 1
    while (idx1 + length) <= string.length
      substring = string.slice(idx1, length)***

      if palindrome?(substring) && (best_palindrome == nil || substring.length > best_palindrome.length)
        best_palindrome = substring
      end

      length += 1
    end

    idx1 += 1
  end

  return best_palindrome
end


def longest_palindrome(string)
  longest = nil

  i = 0
  ***while i < string.length
    i2 = 1
    while i2 < string.length***
      if palindrome?(string.slice(i, i2)) == true && (longest == nil || string.slice(i, i2).length > longest.length)
        longest = string.slice(i, i2) 
      end
      i2 += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  return longest
end
```

Comment: That's programming. A slight modification can make a big difference. Often, the modified code does not even run (except in Perl).

Comment: Please show your error message.

Comment: @Aetherus The assignment provides a couple test strings, and one results in false. I'll add it to the OP

Comment: Is there any reason you've rendered this unusable by spiking in a bunch of asterisks? In any case you have a classic *off-by-one* error.

Comment: Sorry I could not figure out how to bold/highlight that part of the code so I used a couple asterisks. Every other part of the two methods are identical in function as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code...

```
while i2 < string.length
```

... means you're never checking the maximum possible length.

`"abba".slice(0,4)` is the entire string, but you only ever go up to `"abba".slice(0,3)` which is "abb".

So you never test the entire string.

Change the line to...

```
 while i2 <= string.length
```

...and it should be ok.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am still a beginner. Isn't the last a in "abba" index 3? Since it starts at 0.

Comment: Yes but slice arguments are not start/end they are start/length